# Does aspiration propagate to the following vowel?

Tags: phonetics, pronunciation, korean, aspiration, stops

My native language is Korean, which is notorious for its three-way distinction (plain vs. tense vs. aspirated) of (non-nasal) stops. As such, I tried to analyze my own pronunciation.

Then I found that when I pronounce word-initial plain stops (ㄱ/ㄷ/ㅂ/ㅈ), the following vowel is initially (or sometimes entirely) breathy, while for tense stops (ㄲ/ㄸ/ㅃ/ㅉ), the vowel remains modal. For example, 불 [pṳl] vs. 뿔 [pul].

Yet for aspirated stops (ㅋ/ㅌ/ㅍ/ㅊ), I cannot pinpoint whether the following vowel is modal or breathy. The stop sounds like ㅋ/ㅌ/ㅍ/ㅊ regardlessly, e.g. Both [pʰul] and [pʰṳl] sounds like 풀. (The breathy glide doesn't seem to exceed that of 불 in duration, though.)

What about other speakers (of any language that has aspirated consonants)? To re-phrase the title question, does the [ʰ] moment overlap the following vowel?